# _jsxDev is not a function when using MDXRemote

Tags: reactjs, next.js

[image]

I am creating a blog using Next.js and mdx.

I began by following this entire [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MrjeefD8sac). He made the blog using nextjs and md.

Then, I followed one part in this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/WCGopHwXnic?t=2686) to switch from using md to mdx

However, the one line of code below is causing the error in the picture for some reason

```
 <MDXRemote {...props.mdxSource} components={components} />
```

entire code

```
import fs from 'fs'
import matter from 'gray-matter'
import { serialize } from 'next-mdx-remote/serialize'
import { MDXRemote } from 'next-mdx-remote'

import path from 'path'

export default function Post(props) {
    const components = {}

    return (
        <>
            // this line of code is causing error
            <MDXRemote {...props.mdxSource} components={components} />

        </>
    )
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {    
    const markdownWithMeta = fs.readFileSync(
        path.join('posts', slug + '.mdx'),
        'utf-8'
    )
    const { content } = matter(markdownWithMeta)
    const mdxSource = await serialize(content)

    return {
        props: {            
            mdxSource,            
        },
    }
}
```

Package I'm using: https://github.com/hashicorp/next-mdx-remote

Answer (score 10):

Instead of downgrading, you can use { development: false } as suggested in github issues.

```
  const mdxSource = await serialize(source, {
    mdxOptions: { development: false },
  });
```

https://github.com/hashicorp/next-mdx-remote/issues/324

Answer (score 0):

Same issue. Downgrade to "^3.0.8"

Comment: can confirm this works (next 12, react 17)

Comment: ok but I'm using react 18. What could solve?

Answer (score 0):

It works if you force-downgrade `@mdx-js` to `2.1.5`:

Add to you `package.json`:

`yarn`

```
"resolutions": {
    "@mdx-js/mdx": "2.1.5",
    "@mdx-js/react": "2.1.5"
},
```

`npm`

```
 "overrides": {
    "@mdx-js/mdx": "2.1.5",
    "@mdx-js/react": "2.1.5"
  }
```

Answer (score -3):

You need use `npm run build & npm run start` because you need to generate static pages